# Erro ao abrir página aspnet C#. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, relatório, reportviewer, hospedagem

Boa noite pessoal.

Desenvolvi um site, que em determinada página, mostra um relatório. Localmente funciona normalmente, mas quando executo na página publicada, dá o erro:

```html
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:


Line 14:         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
Line 15: 
Line 16:         <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="100%" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%">
Line 17:             <LocalReport ReportPath="relatorios\cadastro\cliente\rptCliente.rdlc">
Line 18:                 <DataSources>


Source File: E:\Domains\precisorapido.com.br\wwwroot\relatorios\cadastro\cliente\RelCliente.aspx    Line: 16

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport..ctor() +0
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy..ctor(ServerReport serverReport) +104
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.CreateReportHierarchy() +51
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer..ctor() +294
   ASP.relatorios_cadastro_cliente_relcliente_aspx.__BuildControlReportViewer1() in E:\Domains\precisorapido.com.br\wwwroot\relatorios\cadastro\cliente\RelCliente.aspx:16
   ASP.relatorios_cadastro_cliente_relcliente_aspx.__BuildControlform1() in E:\Domains\precisorapido.com.br\wwwroot\relatorios\cadastro\cliente\RelCliente.aspx:12
   ASP.relatorios_cadastro_cliente_relcliente_aspx.__BuildControlTree(relatorios_cadastro_cliente_relcliente_aspx __ctrl) in E:\Domains\precisorapido.com.br\wwwroot\relatorios\cadastro\cliente\RelCliente.aspx:1
   ASP.relatorios_cadastro_cliente_relcliente_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() in E:\domains\precisorapido.com.br\_rhfiles\aspnet\root\75bebe76\acefe9a3\App_Web_zwfsn2gh.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +48
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +22
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.relatorios_cadastro_cliente_relcliente_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in E:\domains\precisorapido.com.br\_rhfiles\aspnet\root\75bebe76\acefe9a3\App_Web_zwfsn2gh.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +188
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2114.0
```

No References do meu código, tem as dll´s:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que tem de errado?

Comment: Você chegou a olhar na pasta bin do projeto publicado se as dlls estão la: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common?

Comment: Estão sim @d-aguilar. Eu atualizei o ReporterViewer e não deu mais este erro. Agora dá o seguinte erro:  

    An error occurred during local report processing.
        The report definition for report 'rptCliente' has not been specified
            Could not find file 'E:\Domains\precisorapido.com.br\wwwroot\relatorios\cadastro\cliente\rptCliente.rdlc'. 

Lembrando que localmente funciona.

Comment: Rodrigo, geralmente quando publicamos, os arquivos rdlc não são copiados para o servidor. Veja se este arquivo rptCliente.rdlc foi publicado no servidor.

Comment: De fato não foi. Colocarei e farei o teste. Obrigado.

Comment: Coloquei o arquivo .rdlc e agora o erro mudou. Ficou: 

    An error occurred during local report processing.
        The definition of the report 'relatorios\cadastro\cliente\rptCliente.rdlc' is invalid.
            An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
                Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.